# Website spontaneously freezes in Chrome - how to debug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, freeze

I build this
http://ipl.janstudt.de/
website which is supposed to run on the iPad (it does) and in Google Chrome. In Chrome (on Win 7 64bit), after a seemingly random time of a few minutes, the browser freezes. Also, sometimes when I click the "Reload Page" button in Chrome while on this site, the Browser also freezes. In both cases, the Browser recovers after 10-20 seconds.

How do I get to the bottom of this? There are no Javascript Errors. The memory footprint is very modest and does not increase over time (according to the heap snapshots). There are no plugins involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really doubt it is your script; rather, I think it is Chrome doing something silly. I would test it on other similar systems to see if you can reproduce it. I've had it running on mine for about 5 minutes with no issues (Win7, 64bit, Chrome 5.0.375.127).

You could try to keep the profiler running and catch the freeze-up, but I think that would just be a waste of time.

Comment: I will definitely try this out on different PCs maybe it's really just a Chrome hiccup.

Comment: Yeah, I had your site up for at least 20-30 minutes with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Landed here while dealing with similar issue. Got a solution by changing hardware acceleration settings 
FYI:
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/daV0DhOXKVI/oBPZ6pUtBgAJ